# Flattening list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, which may or may not have similar keys, and I want to flatten the list into a single dictionary, with a list type for values.

An example of this as follows:

```
data =  [{'category': u'Non-profit organization', 'categories': [u'Theater',
      u'Bar', u'Concert Venue']}, {'category': u'Non-profit organization', 
      'categories': [u'Business Services', u'College & University']}]
```

This should become the following:

```
print result
result = {'category': [u'Non-profit organization', u'Non-profit 
      organization'], 'categories': [u'Theater', u'Bar', u'Concert Venue',       
      u'Business Services', u'College & University']]}
```

As you can see, anything that is a string value in the initial data should be added as a value within a list. Anything that is held in list type in the initial dictionary should be added it its key, but to create a flattened list.

Clearly a simple solution is to `for loop` through it all and append values, but am looking for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)
for dic in data:
    for key, value in dic.items():
        old_value = res[key]
        if isinstance(value, list):
            old_value.extend(value)
        else:
            old_value.append(value)

        # alternatively:
        old_value += [value] if not isinstance(value, list) else value
```

The reasoning is: in the end you want all values to be `list`s. The difference is that values that originally where lists should be joined together (and `list.extend` does that) while other values should be inserted in a new list (as in `list.append`).

---

Also, there is no built-in method nor class in the `collections` module that does this automatically, so I believe the above is probably "optimal" as far as code dimension, readability and efficiency are considered.

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking along this, but wondered if there was something even simpler. Just as an improvement, by stating the defaultdict, we have no reason to assign the old_val variable, as we can directly extend and append to the dictionart

Answer (score 0):

In additional previous answer (sorry, I haven't enough reputation to write a comment) you need to check if value in `res` otherwise you will have repeat values:

```
{'category': [u'Non-profit organization', u'Non-profit organization'], 'categories': [u'Theater', u'Bar', u'Concert Venue', u'Business Services', u'College & University']}
```

twice `u'Non-profit organization'`